# how to get list of files from directory using java

Tags: java

I want to get the list of java files in a folder.
For example, i will provide the input as "c:\main\java"
Inside java, there will be package structure like "c:\maina\java\io\ci\", where java files will be present in ci folder.

now i want to write code to list those java files from the folder.

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so we can help you see where you are going wrong

Comment: well. File.getName() and File.isDirectory() are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

use Apache `Fileutils listFiles` method

```
public static Collection<File> listFiles(File directory,
                         String[] extensions,
                         boolean recursive)
```

and pass the extension string array values as java

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
String path = "your file path"; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   System.out.println(files);
      }
  }
```